# assembly 86 - 2numbers input and divide

Tags: assembly

i got into truble in assembly x86 assignment.
the request from the program is:
get 2 numbers, word size, from the user and divine them.
print the division result and the leftovers from the result.

i wrote a code, but i got trubles with the input.

```
;get 2 positive numbers
;print the div and leftovers
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 64
.DATA
    num1    dw ?
    num2    dw ?
    dResult dw ? ;divide result
    lResult dw ? ;leftovers from divide result
    MSG1    db "enter first number: " ,'$'
    MSG2    db "enter second number: " ,'$'
    new_line db 0dh, 0ah,  '$'
.CODE
main    PROC
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    call    getFirst
    call    newLine
    call    getSecond
    call    newLine
    call    divide

    call    printResult

    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h
ENDP
;print results
printResult PROC
    ;print divide result
    mov ah, 09
    lea dx, dResult
    int 21H
    call    newLine
    ;print leftovers from divide
    mov ah, 09
    lea dx, lResult
    int 21H
    ret
ENDP
;divide 2 numbers
;put the result and leftover in variables
divide      PROC
    mov ax, num1
    cmp ax, num2
    jl lower ;if num1 lower then num2
    div num2
    jmp finish
    lower:
    mov ax, num2
    div num1
    finish:
    sub ax, '0' ;switch hex to dec
    mov dResult, ax
    sub dx, '0' ;switch hex to dec
    mov lResult, dx
    ret
ENDP
getFirst    PROC
;print MSG1
    mov ah, 09
    lea dx, MSG1
    int 21H
;get first number input
    mov ah, 0AH
    lea dx, num1
    int 21H
    ret
ENDP
getSecond   PROC
;print MSG2
    mov ah, 09
    lea dx, MSG2
    int 21H
;get second number input
    mov ah, 0AH
    lea dx, num2
    int 21H 
    ret
ENDP
;new line
newLine     PROC
    lea dx, new_line
    mov ah, 09
    int 21H
    ret
ENDP    
END     main
```

Comment: int 21 function 0A returns the whole string, not the binary representation of the number you have entered (and requires some prerequisites for the buffer used) ... you have to convert this string into binary before you use is. also keep in mind, that div is doing a 32bit DX:AX division, when the parameter given is 16 bit

Comment: Much better to use `idiv` with all explicit operands. Using `div` is masochistic.

Comment: @Johan `idiv` has the same forms as `div`, you are probably confusing it with `imul`. Also, masochistic or not, if your operands are unsigned that's what you need.